# Does someone know any user reputation engines?

Tags: python, django, web

I develop website and would like to add reputation value to each user. So I'm looking for user reputation engine with features like:

- good reputation model
- users gain reputation when it do something what is liked by other users
- users with bigger reputation has bigger influence to other reputations
- exclude cyclic reputation exchange
- ...

Does someone know is there any implementions of such an engine? First of all I'm interested in python/django implementations but any other are interesting for me too.

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) what you're looking for?

Comment: What the Django Community site down?  http://www.djangoproject.com/community/  Or did you want me to search it for you?

Comment: I suspect the wrong things is that users with bigger reputation has bigger influence to other reputations. Removing it would exclude cyclic reputation exchange.

Comment: @tjameson no, I need something like [this](http://imhonet.ru/about/reputation/) (russian site) but that is not opensource and not even free, so I would like to know any competitors

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with a particular open-source product that works out of the box, but [Randy Farmer](http://www.linkedin.com/in/frandallfarmer) has recently written an O'Reilly book on [Building Online Communities](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596159801) that is quite helpful.

This SO topic may also help with building your own: [Karma/reputation system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668756/karma-reputation-system)